# Cannot configure MacOS sshd to accept signed certificates for authentication

Tags: macos, ssh, certificate, sshd

We're adding some Mac Minis to our environment, and need them to allow SSH access via signed certificates, the same as we do on Linux. Unfortunately, it's failing.

We have configured `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to look at the signing authority keys file (`/private/etc/ssh/trusted-user-ca-keys.pem`). There's no daemon to restart, and we're seeing that the file is being parsed for other changes we make, but it is simply not reading the trusted signing keys.

`ssh -vvvv <target>` from another client shows a simple:

> receive packet: type 51

meaning authentication failed. Well no kidding!

We can get public key authentication working without a problem.

What am I missing?

EDIT: To answer questions, they're running Darwin 21.4.0, and Openssh 8. 6p1. Man pages are the same as on Linux - to the point that they assume sshd is running as an actual daemon, instead of the Mac JIT service.

Comment: What version of macOS? What version of sshd? How does that compare to the sshd version you're using on Linux? If the macOS version is older, have you looked at its documentation to see if it supports the same thing the same way? What does ssh**d**'s verbose output say?